# Storing elements of a ListView Internal Storage or SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, listview

In my app I have following data structure:

- A ListView that user can add, delete, rename or edit elements, achieved using an action bar menu.
- From the first selection, there is a second action bar menu, offering the same thing, but of different elements
- After editing the second ListView, a third and final ListView comes into play, with the same options as the first and second ones.

The overall data structure is mainly lists holding lists of elements. What would be the best way to store this data to files Internal Storage or SQLite? I lack experience with both of those and am not sure where I need to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use a sqlite database as you have a proper interface to add, manipulate, delete and retrieve the data. Also it is easy to use the listadapters to provide your listviews with the data stored in the sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier from a development standpoint to use a SQLite database. That lets you use CursorAdapters on your ListViews. You should have a table for each ListView, but is should be fairly simple.

Also, I think that a database will have better performance than a serialized object or settings file.